# Should I have 2 separated classes, one for the "logic" and one for the "graphic interface"?

Tags: c++, qt, architecture

I'm developping a little to train myself to C++ and to the framework Qt.

I have severals classes such as : Monster, Weapon, Item, etc...
The basics use cases of the game are things like: pick a monster to fight against within a selection of monsters, or buy a weapon within a selection of weapons.

So I need to display thoses things, so I created a Widget class for each of thoses classes: MonsterWidget, WeaponWidget and so on.

> MonsterWidget.h

```
class MonsterWidget : public QWidget{
    QLabel healthPoint;
    QLabel baseDamage;
    Monster monster;

    void updateLabelsFromMonsterObject;
}
```

> Monster.h

```
class Monster{
    int healthPoint;
    int baseDamage;

    bool isAlive();
    void attack();
    ...
}
```

And I'm thinking that I could also do like that:

> MonsterRefacto.h

```
class MonsterWidget : public QWidget{
    QLabel healthPoint;
    QLabel baseDamage;
    int healthPoint;
    int baseDamage;

    void updateLabelsFromValues();
    bool isAlive();
    void attack();
    ...
}
```

But because I don't have a lot of experience I don't know what would be the best in my case, if I should have 2 separated classes, one for the "logic" and one for the "graphic interface" or should I merge them ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about design patterns.
In your case, try to use MVC pattern.
And separate logic from view.